# I need help adding this code to jQuery function .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Irina said in another thread, "I have a responsive fixed top menu that opens after clicking on the Menu icon. Then I would like to hide it after clicking on one of the menu items. Otherwise it covers part of the section that slides up."

She said she made this work by adding a line of code to the following jQuery function. But Where do I place this code in the jQuery function to make this work?  I'm not a coder so please help me by being specific. Thanks.

This code:

```
$('.menu-item').click(function() { $('#menu-primary-menu').slideToggle(); });
```

goes somewhere in the code below.

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

$("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu").addClass("responsive-menu").before('<div class="responsive-menu-icon"></div>');

$(".responsive-menu-icon").click(function(){
    $(this).next("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu").slideToggle();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 600) {
        $("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu, nav .sub-menu").removeAttr("style");
        $(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").removeClass("menu-open");
    }
});

$(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").click(function(event){
    if (event.target !== this)
    return;
        $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").slideToggle(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("menu-open");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you share the markup ?

Comment: link to Irina's question & put the code after the `jQuery(function( $ ){`

Answer (score 0):

You already have `click` event on `menu-item` inside `$(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").click(function(event){` code, try adding `$('#menu-primary-menu').slideToggle();` inside it. Try below

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

$("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu").addClass("responsive-menu").before('<div class="responsive-menu-icon"></div>');

$(".responsive-menu-icon").click(function(){
    $(this).next("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu").slideToggle();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 600) {
        $("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu, nav .sub-menu").removeAttr("style");
        $(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").removeClass("menu-open");
    }
});

$(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").click(function(event){
    if (event.target !== this)
    return;
        $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").slideToggle(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("menu-open");
        $('#menu-primary-menu').slideToggle();
    });
});
```